# How to Validate multiple forms in the parent?

Tags: reactjs, components, antd

I'm using Ant Design.
I have two components. Activities (Step of Stepper) and ActivityForm.  In activities I can add activities. Each activity is a form.

I need to validate all forms when the user press next. In order to validate all forms I need to have all forms in the parent and then I might iterate them.

Ant design provides a decorator that injects props. In particular, I need this.props.validateForm.

**ActivityForm:**

```
render() {
    return (
        <Form key={form_id}>
           ...
        </Form>)
}
```

**Activities**

AddActivity:

```
    const activity = (
        <Collapse.Panel header={'Activity ' + id} key={id}>
                <ActivityForm  {...this.props} />
        </Collapse.Panel>
    );

    this.setState({
        activities: [...this.state.activities, activity]
    })
```

render:

```
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <Collapse} accordion>
                    {this.state.activities}
                </Collapse>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <Button type="primary">
                        Next
                    </Button>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `this.props.form` in each child step, so that you can validate them in parent like:

```
<Step1 form={this.props.form} />
<Step2 form={this.props.form} />
```

And then you can validate in `next()` by using `this.props.form.validateFields` or `this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll` [as per documentation](https://ant.design/components/form/#validateFields/validateFieldsAndScroll). You need to provide the fields name of the step you want to validate in condition as given below:

```
next() {
    if (this.state.current === 0) {
        this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll(["first"], (err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                const current = this.state.current + 1;
                this.setState({ current });
            }
        });
    } else if (this.state.current === 1) {
        this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll(["second"], (err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                const current = this.state.current + 1;
                this.setState({ current });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have created a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xv74yy0lpp).